# Do we need [utilities] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag named [utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utilities) (a symlink to [tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)). It seems redundant to me. Is there a real need for it? Could someome who cares for it actually write a tag wiki for it?

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do without it. The utilities tag has almost full overlap with [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell). The few cases that do not overlap would specifically be better tagged with some other combination of tags.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem rather vague; could a question be tagged *only* [utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utilities) ?

If not then this meets the definition of [a meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 0):

I think [utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utilities) is a fine tag. It's for shell commands that aren't important enough to have their own tag. It's a way to have more specific tags than the very general [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) and [command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line).

It's true that it's sometimes used in a meta-ish way: on some questions, it doesn't seem to provide any information. On a couple, it means “I want to do this on the command line”, and we use [command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) for that. But this means that these questions should be retagged, and I've just done just that. Since I feel the tag does convey useful information, I'll leave it on the other questions.

There's now a tag wiki, as well.